# Displaying Data in table with ng-repeat dynamically for json array object

Tags: angularjs

[After using ng-repeat i have the data displayed in this format, but i want "battersID" column to be displayed in the single cell or as shown in other picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0GVsx.png)

my html code snippet is as posted below,

```html
<tr ng-repeat="items in list >
        <td>{{items.id}}</td>
        <td>{{items.type}}</td>
        <td>{{items.name}}</td> 
        <td ng-repeat="batters in items.batters"> {{batters.id}}</td>  
          
</tr>
```

the above code display the data in Table as shown in above picture 
[I need the data to be displayed as shown in the picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/glZvR.png)

My example json file,

```
[
    {
        "id": "0001",
        "type": "donut",
        "name": "Cake",
        "ppu": 0.55,
        "batters":
        [
            { "id": "1001", "type": "Regular" },
            { "id": "1003", "type": "Blueberry" },
            { "id": "1004", "type": "Devil's Food" }
        ],

    },
    {
        "id": "0002",
        "type": "sample",
        "name": "sample",
        "ppu": 0.55,
        "batters":
        [
            { "id": "1001", "type": "Regular" },

        ],

    },
    {
        "id": "0003",
        "type": "test",
        "name": "test",
        "ppu": 0.55,
        "batters":
        [
            { "id": "1001", "type": "Regular" },
            { "id": "1003", "type": "Blueberry" },

        ],

    },
    {
        "id": "0001",
        "type": "donut",
        "name": "Cake",
        "ppu": 0.55,
        "batters":
        [
            { "id": "1001", "type": "Regular" },
            { "id": "1003", "type": "Blueberry" },
            { "id": "1004", "type": "Devil's Food" }
            { "id": "1001", "type": "Regular" },
            { "id": "1003", "type": "Blueberry" },
        ],

    }
]
```

Comment: and what did you try exactly?

Comment: You should try to solve your problem on your own. Then if you get stuck, post it here and we will help you. This portal is not for making others do your work.

Comment: i have tried it using ng-repeat and i have displayed it in the table format, but the "batters.id" may have multiple values and i want it to be displayed as i have shown in above picture. at present the Batters.id is getting displayed in same row.

Answer (score 0):

Use `ng-repeat` and in the `ng-reapeat` write code like this :

`ng-repeat="key in controllerName.varName"`

Example:

```
<div ng-repeat="test in testController.varName"><div>{{test.id}}</div><div>{test.type}}</div></div>

varName = Your JsonArray;
```